# Adding a Read-Only View using Update Model from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I am trying to add a read only View to the Entity Data Model using the *update model from database* option in the .edmx file. I have been googling this issue into the ground and every site I go to and question I click on says that I need to add a primary key. I know that adding this view is possible because I have done this before using the same database, I just don't remember how I did it. I can't add a key to the view because it is read-only so that answer won't work for me. I know that this question has been asked before but to be quite honest they all link back to the same questions that do not provide a good answer. I am 100% sure that I can add this view to the entity model and after I figure it out I will post here on how to do it if no one else can tell me how. In the mean time I thought I would ask you guys if you might know how I can add this view to the model. Thanks for your help! Hope you have a great day!

Comment: where's your problem : you have a problem trying to add the view ? does it generate an error ? you don't see the view in the edmx after adding it ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes, the view is available when I try to add it using the update model from database option, but after I click finish the view is not in the .edmx file. I am sure it is because the view is read only and does not contain a primary key. As I said in the question I have been able to add same view before, I just don't remember how and my boss accidentally deleted our entire database so I am trying to rebuild it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with a read-only view, it needs PKs (to uniquely identify rows) to properly retrieve from the database.

Also, the PKs need to be non-nullable fields.  I've had to add ISNULL(Field, 0) as Field in my Views' select statements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I remember to have faced the same case.

If it's the same :

Open your edmx with an xml editor (Visual Studio, open with...).

You should have a reference to your view in the file, but commented.

If that's still true (that was my case), the solution can be found here :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/fbc69ed3-dd2e-4308-bbf2-0ce330526a4f

First Solution (adding keys) is ok : you add keys to the model, not to your view.
But if you do an update model from database, these changes will be lost...

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I also found this blog during my extreme googling and searching of stack overflow for this problem. I can't use this solution though because the View never gets added to the .edmx file because of the lack of a primary key. The only part I remember having to do was having to click on "Generate Database from model" after I had added the View to the .edmx file. So I am stuck until I remember or figure out how to add the View to the .edmx file. Thanks for your idea though!